# Regex in SAS to convert <= as #8805 to LE

Tags: regex, sas

I use;
`prxparse("s/<[a-zA-Z\/][^>]*>//")` to clean up a string of the vast majority of HTML tags I find. But I need to add something to convert &#8805 which is a <= but where the < is above the - in the same space.

I'd like to convert it to either "LE" or "<=" ... I've tried a number of things but none seem to work. I'm pretty new at regular expressions so if someone out there could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as this is plain-text HTML, you can just use

```
s/&#8805;/ LE /
```

Nothing in that is a regular expression metacharacter.  It might need spaces around LE to avoid collisions.

Fully in SAS:

```
data test;
format htmlcode $15.;
input htmlcode $;
html_parsed = prxchange('s/&#8805;/ LE /',-1,htmlcode);
put _all_;
datalines4;
x&#8805;15
x &#8805; 15
;;;;
run;
```

Comment: SAS required that I add the following line above the input; REGEX2 = prxparse("s/&#8805;/ <= /"); and then call it like this; call prxchange(REGEX2, -1,htmlcode); It errored out when I tried to do it as in the example. Thanks for the help guys

Comment: Worked fine in the example for me, so not sure what issue you might've had with it; but glad it worked in the end.